# str.each in Ruby isn't working

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-1.9

I'm Learning Ruby.

I found the method `String#each` at http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html.

When I try using it...

```
irb(main):001:0> "hello\nworld".each {|s| p s}
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for "hello\nworld":String
```

...but I get that `NoMethodError`.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.1p253 so I don't think I'm using an old version.  What's going on?

Answer (score 37):

Ruby 1.9 no longer has `each` on the `String` class.  Use either `each_char` or `each_line` depending on what you want to do. The docs for Ruby 1.9 `String` are http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html.

Answer (score 10):

Use `each_char` instead:

```
"hello\nworld".each_char {|s| p s}
```

as to why it's not working, it works in 1.8 but not 1.9.

Comment: `String#each` iterated by line, not char.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at the docs for 1.8. String#each has been removed in 1.9. Use each_line instead.

Answer (score 2):

Works in 1.8.7, doesn't show up in the 1.9 docs -- must have been deprecated.

Here we go: https://web.archive.org/web/20090423003136/http://eigenclass.org/hiki.rb?Changes+in+Ruby+1.9#l113