# Failing to synchronize to repository in Tooltwist Designer

Tags: tooltwist

When trying to synchronize changes to the repository, I am receiving the following error:

```
[designer@ip-address ~]$ ruby /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb /home/designer/server/webdesign-projects/webdesign list
 M navpoints/project.xml
 M properties.xml
?? widgets/project_pages/training/7a12a84b6942f195f71bec5d5d8c68caec753293/

/home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:28:in `block in main_list': undefined method `each' for #<String:0x00000002345128> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:21:in `chdir'
    from /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:21:in `main_list'
    from /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:455:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/lib_trollop.rb:740:in `with_standard_exception_handling'
    from /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb:448:in `<main>'
```

I am getting this error on a newly deployed tooltwist designer in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will is caused by the version of Ruby you are using. In Ruby 1.9 the function `String:each` was replaced with `String:each_line` (See [str.each in Ruby isn't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104319/str-each-in-ruby-isnt-working)).

You have a choice:

1. Downgrade to Ruby 1.8
2. Edit /home/designer/server/extension-projects/tooltwist/config/bin/syncWithGit.rb and replace ***each*** with ***each_line***.
3. Upgrade to ToolTwist v8.3 and use the ToolTwist command line interface to run your Designer. See step 4 in https://github.com/tooltwist/documentation/wiki/Deploying-with-the-v8.3-Controller.