# String matching regex syntax issue

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to write a method to pulls out every string that matches the criteria from a large text file:

- Every element is separated by a comma
- The first 5 elements could be any number from 1-59
- The next 21 elements should be numbers from 1-5
- The next 27 elements could be either true or false (no caps)
- The final 5 elements are integers from 1-5

My code:

```
#this string should be returned by the regex matching
str="3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3"
matchResult=/[1-59]{5}[1-5]{21}[true|false]{27}[1-5]{5}/.match(str)
matchResult.each{|x| #this doesnt work....why?
    puts x
}
```

- What is the correct way to print all matches? `matchResult.each` throws an error. I thought it returned an array of matches.
- How can I adjust my regex to expect a comma between every value (not at the ends of the string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put true or false inside a capturing group or non-capturing group like `(?:true|false)` so that it would match the exact `true` or `false` substring , this `[true|false]` will match a single character only whether it may be `t` or `r` or `u` or `e` or `|` ,....

```
> str="3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3"
> str.match(/^(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])){4}(?:,[1-5]){21}(?:,(?:true|false)){27}(?:,[1-5]){5}$/)
=> #<MatchData "3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3">
```

Comment: some of my strings might have a comma at the beginning. Is there a way to adjust the regex for that? I tried:  (/^(?:[,]*)(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])(?:,(?:[1-5]\d|[1-9])){4}(?:,[1-5]){21}(?:,(?:true|false)){27}(?:,[1-5]){5}$/) but that didnt work

Comment: how your string looks like?

Comment: str=",3,15,14,31,40,5,5,4,5,3,4,4,5,2,2,2,1,2,1,1,3,3,3,2,4,3,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,3,3,3,2,3"

Answer (score 1):

In regards to your first question:

> *"What is the correct way to print all matches? matchResult.each throws an error. I thought it returned an array of matches."*

The Regex `.match` method doesn't return an array of matches; it returns either a match object (in this case, a string, since you're calling `.match` on a string) or nil if there are no matches [(see docs here)](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Regexp.html#method-i-match).

This means `matchResult` is a string, and you can't call `.each` on a string, which is why you're getting an error message. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104319/str-each-in-ruby-isnt-working) for more info on `.each` & strings.

Comment: Thanks, you pointed me in the right direction. It turns out I had to use scan rather then match

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. And using `.scan` instead makes sense. Nice job working that out.