# Cap production deploy - Rails 6 - Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano, ruby-on-rails-6

Trying to deploy a rails 6 application to a Digital Ocean droplet.

I run `cap production deploy` and it fails with this error:

```
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 256
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000565323a30eb8>
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:AppName>'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rdevc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/rdevc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

Tasks: TOP => deploy:assets:prepare
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: rake exit status: 256
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000565323a30eb8>
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:AppName>'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/Rakefile:4:in `require_relative'
/var/www/html/Dev/rails/AppName/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/rdevc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/rdevc/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any idea what causes this?
The gem dependencies are all satisfied and the server is running the same versions of ruby, rails and ubuntu as I have on my dev box.

Comment: What version of Ruby do you use? This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2104319/str-each-in-ruby-isnt-working#2104345

Comment: What's there on line `config/application.rb:10`?

Comment: Line 10 is just ```class Application < Rails::Application```, which of course makes no sense. Ruby version is 2.5.1p57.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had endless problems deploying this app. Credentials problems, sassc nightmares and more. In the end, I started a new 5.2.2 project, copied in the controllers, models, migrations, views, routes, etc., and changed a few instances of [6.0] to [5.2]. First try deployed perfectly and the app is now live. I can only assume there is something not fully working with my rails 6 install.
Thanks for your replies, guys.